# PHP error uploading file

Tags: php, file, upload

Okay, so I set up an upload engine for a website so that an authenticated user can upload a audio file (a key) for a song in the library, but I come across this strange problem when I try to upload any file over 5MB.

**I set my php.ini max filesize to 50MB by the way**

Everything uploads properly, but there is no data associated with the file on the other end.

HTML CODE:

```
<form action="keyUpload.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p style="color:#fff;font-size:30px;font-family:Times">
Add a new Key:<br/><input name="uploaded" type="file" id="file"><br />
<input type="text" name="kname" id="kname" value placeholder="Key Name (Ex. Demo, A#, etc.)" style="width:300px;"><br/>
<button class="button">Upload File</button><br/>
<span style="font-size:12px;">*Max Filesize is 50 MB*</span>
</p>
</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php 
$id=$_GET["id"];
$name=$_POST["kname"];

$name = str_replace(" ","%20",$name);

$allowed_filetypes = array('.mp3','.m4a','.wav','.wma');

$filename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
```

Both $filename and $ext are empty variables when I upload a file larger than 5 MB. In all other cases, this engine works perfectly.

When echoed, simply nothing happens, so obviously the engine will not save the file if it doesn't exist. What's going on?

var_dump:

```
array(0) { }
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for upload errors:

```
if ($_FILES['uploaded']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['uploaded']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are defined here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

As well, do NOT use filenames to validate the uploads. It is beyond trivial for a malicious user to fake a filename and upload malicious files, eg.

```
ren nastyvirus.exe good_tune.mp3
```

And don't use string operations on filenames. There's a whole whack of PHP functions for filename manipulation, e.g. http://php.net/basename

Comment: All I got from doing that was "Upload failed with error code " and nothing else. Also, I know all of the people that will be using this personally, so there is no need to be worried about malicious use. ;)

Comment: Interesting, should've output at least a number. What does a `var_dump($_FILES)` show? paste that as code above, since comments are a bad place to put formatted dumps

Comment: var dump just returned what I added above.

Comment: ok. so there's no file upload occuring at all. No idea, but that's the problem. If there was an upload that failed, you'd get at least SOME data in $_FILEs.

Comment: I found it. Turns out when I changed the max filesize in the ini, I overlooked the max post-size, defaulted to 5M! Thanks for your help! +1

Answer (score 0):

Set `max_post_size` in php.ini as well.

Comment: Don't you mean `post_max_size`?

Comment: One should also not forget `upload_max_filesize` too. [http://php.net/upload-max-filesize](http://php.net/upload-max-filesize)