# File not uploading to directory - even when www-data has group permission in the upload folder

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-permissions

I have got this to work with 777 file permission: but cannot understand why more restrictive file permissions will not work.

**Linux Groups:**

1. alex
2. www-data

**Linux Users:**

1. alex (belongs to www-data and alex)
2. www-data (belongs to www-data and alex)

**Directory Structure**

uploads (directory,owner=alex,group=alex,chmod=660)

**Problem**

A PHP/Wordpress Admin form (on apache) is used to upload a file to this directory.  If the folder permissions are anything below 777, even 766, the file will not upload, and I cannot understand why.

Comment: you need to check and echo an error while doing so .. something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291068/php-error-uploading-file

Comment: For more http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: To check if directory is writable or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109188/how-do-i-check-if-a-directory-is-writeable-in-php

Comment: Note: `777` is the evil number for an server-admin guy.